# Inequality Prove that you can cross out

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone show me how I can conclude that $b(x^2-xy+y^2) <= c(x^2-xy+y^2)$ can be shown to be $b<=c$

Comment: I want to know how you can cross out $(x^2-xy+y^2)$

Comment: You can do it if you know it's positive.

Comment: If we assume $(x^2 - xy + y^2) > 0$, then we can divide it out.

Comment: @dustin How do you prove that they are positive?

Comment: @Nishant How can I prove that?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @dustin No there isn't.

Comment: If we add and subtract $xy$ to it, we have $x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + xy = (x - y)^2 + xy > 0$ or $(x - y)^2 > -xy$ but I don't know if this is any help besides a new condition that needs to be met.

Comment: @dustin I think that would complicate it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x,y$ are both zero, nothing can be concluded about the other variables, you just get $0=0$ and that's all.

Otherwise, $$ 4(x^2 -xy+ y^2) = (2x-y)^2 + 3 y^2 = 3 x^2 + (-x+2y)^2 $$
and is positive, because either $3y^2$ or $3x^2$ is nonzero.